# Drupal Foundation top bar toggle not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, zurb-foundation

I started to design a website using drupal and the [Zurb foundation theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/zurb_foundation)
I added some pages. The pages appear in the top bar. When the screen gets smaller, all my pages disappear in the top bar and a `menu` item shows up with a icon with 3 stripes. But when i click this `menu` item, nothing happens.

Here is my code of the `page.tpl.php`

```
<?php if ($top_bar): ?>
    <!--.top-bar -->
    <?php if ($top_bar_classes): ?>
    <div class="<?php print $top_bar_classes; ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="contain-to-grid">
        <nav class="top-bar"   data-topbar>
          <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name"><h1><?php print $linked_site_name; ?></h1></li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span><?php print $top_bar_menu_text; ?></span></a></li>
          </ul>

          <section class="top-bar-section">
            <?php if ($top_bar_main_menu) :?>
              <?php print $top_bar_main_menu; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($top_bar_secondary_menu) :?>
              <?php print $top_bar_secondary_menu; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </section>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php if ($top_bar_classes): ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <!--/.top-bar -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

And this code is generated

```
<!--.top-bar -->
            <div class="contain-to-grid">
        <nav class="top-bar"   data-topbar>
          <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name"><h1><a href="/raedthuijs/" rel="home" title="Raedthuijs Home" class="active">Raedthuijs</a></h1></li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
          </ul>

          <section class="top-bar-section">
                              <ul id="main-menu" class="main-nav left"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/raedthuijs/" class="active">Home</a></li><li class="last leaf"><a href="/raedthuijs/?q=node/8">Page 2</a></li></ul>                                                  <ul id="secondary-menu" class="secondary link-list right"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/raedthuijs/?q=user">My account</a></li><li class="last leaf"><a href="/raedthuijs/?q=user/logout">Log out</a></li></ul>                              </section>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
          <!--/.top-bar -->
```

Can you please help me?

[Here](http://www.snipsave.com/user/profile/bertleonaers#9462) is all the generated code by Drupal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not install the jquery update. That was my problem.